# deleting first user from Ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts

I noticed that the username I used to install Ubuntu got added to a bunch of groups in the /etc/group file.  I'm getting rid of unneeded accounts.  Would anything break if I removed that first account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user needs to be in the audio group to use the sound card, as one example. It would make more sense to edit the group file with a text editor, and put your main user in every group the original user was in.

Answer (score 3):

If you've enabled logging in as `root` then no. Otherwise you will need at least one user in the `admin` group so that you have an account able to become root.